# Node.js mysql response format

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I'm developing a node.js app which connects into a MYSQL database, gets some info, converts it into JSON format and write it into the browser.

I'm using the mysql npm (https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql).

```
connection.query("select tact, digits, mode from table1 where id = '"+id+"'", function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
    var objToJson = rows;
    objToJson.response = response;
    var finalresponse = JSON.stringify(objToJson);
});
```

And the final response is:

```
[{"tact":0,"digits":5,"mode":"on"}]
```

The point is that I only want to recieve something like (but it should be json parsed):

```
[{0,5,"on"}]
```

How could I do it? Is it possible?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

To get each values into an array, iterate through it:

```
connection.query("select tact, digits, mode from table1 where id = '"+id+"'", function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
    var objToJson = rows;
    var response = [];
    for (var key in rows) {
        response.push(rows[key]);
    }
    objToJson.response = response;
    var finalresponse = JSON.stringify(objToJson);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to W3Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp) the result can be queried like this:

```
console.log(result[2].address);
```

where address is a column in the dataset.

So since you have selected only 1 record:

```
let tact = result[0].tact;
let digits = result[0].digits;
let mode = result[0].mode
```

gives you the values you want as separate variable. or, you could put these into an array, and then work on.

Dermot